# ViewScript decorator fails to find phtml script

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

My Zend_Form works find, until I add a ViewScript decorator.  Once I add a ViewScript, the form silently fails.  I pretty sure this is a combination of the Zend blank-screen problem (which isn't really a huge issue) and some problem with my viewscript call.

My project is setup thus:

```
/application
/modules
  /default
  / .. other modules ..
  /register
    /controllers
    /forms
      /Options.php
      /_option.phtml
    /models
    /views
      /scripts
```

My form:

```
class Register_Form_Options extends Zend_Form
{
  init()
  {
    $field = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('Options');
    $field
      ->setLabel($row->Name)
      ->addValidator('int');
    $list= array( /* select options here*/ );
    $field->addMultiOptions($list);
    $field->setDecorators(array(array('ViewScript',array('viewModule'=>'register','viewScript'=>'forms/_option.phtml'))));
    $this->addElement($field);
  }
}
```

The file `_option.phtml` currently contains just text.

When I comment out the ViewScript line, the form renders inside my view.  When I leave it in, the form does not render at all, but the rest of the view displays.

Any insight will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify a view-script that resides in another module using the `viewModule` option, I would imagine that the framework expects to find it relative to the **view/scripts** folder for that module.

So, I would try moving the `_option.phtml` view-script from:

```
modules/register/forms/_option.phtml
```

to

```
modules/register/views/scripts/forms/_option.phtml
```

and leaving your reference to it in the `setDecorators()` unchanged.